# Does null == null?

Tags: .net, equality

I have an object of type `Foo`.
Foo has an `Id` (int)

a) Is the code bellow "good"?
   b) What should I return if both are null?

```
// overload operator ==
public static bool operator ==(Foo a, Foo b)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(x, y))
    {
        return true;
    }

    if (x == null && y == null)
    {
        return // ??? 
    }

    if (x == null || y == null)
    {
        return false; 
    }

    return x.Id == y.Id; // Ids are the same
}

public static bool Equals(Foo x, Foo y)
{
   return x == y;
}
```

EDIT:
c) Should the **Equals** method call the **== operator**, or viceversa?

Last question
d) Is it possible that 
`ReferenceEquals(x, y) == true` **AND** `x.Id != y.Id`?

Comment: Regarding the last question: it *could* happen. Let's say a property returns `DateTime.Now.Ticks`, then it could be that `x` and `y` refer the same instance, but since the property getter would be called twice it could return different results.

Comment: Good lateral thinking but you surely would not set that Id of your object, would you? This can happen by return a Guid.NewGuid() as well.

Comment: @Aliostad: I was thinking beyond the property name. And yes, any call that potentially return a different value at different times will exhibit this behavior.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes

`null` is nothing but internal Pointer with value zero. So it is comparing two references having value zero.

In fact `object.ReferenceEquals(null, null)` is always true because of this fact so you do not need the second check.

```
if (ReferenceEquals(x, y))
{
    return true;
}

if (x == null && y == null) // THIS CHECK IS REDUNDANT!!!
{
    return true;
}
```

On the last point, == and Equals are handled the same unless on the **boxed value types**:

```
        object s1 = 2;
        object s2 =  1+1;

        Console.WriteLine(s1 == s2);
        Console.WriteLine(s1.Equals(s2));
```

This produces `false` and `true`.

Point d: **NO** it is the same object, the same memory space - if they are pointing to a field on the object.

Comment: So, I will never enter in `if (x == null && y == null)`?

Comment: point d is flat out NO, see comments. if they are pointing to a field on the object.

Comment: If the property is mere returning a field - which an ID would - then no. If it is returning a non-deterministic value such as Guid.NewGuid() then it is really not an ID.

Answer (score 15):

That is actually unreachable code, as `ReferenceEquals()` is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals.aspx) to return `true` if both operands are null.

**EDIT:** To specifically answer your point (d): When `ReferenceEquals` returns `true`, then the two references must be the same; so they point to the same object. So, unless you're doing something unpredictable in the property accessor, the values for the Id will be read from the same object, and would be *expected* to be the same. (Moral of the story here is that properties should behave in a repeatable manner without other side effects like maybe allocating an Id if none is already set)

It is perfectly possible that you could have two objects with the same `Id`, but different references. For example:

```
Foo a = new Foo();
Foo b = new Foo();
```

`ReferenceEquals()` would give false when comparing `a` and `b` (as they are different *instances*), but unless that constructor did anything like allocate an `Id`, I'd expect them to share that Id and your equality check would pass.

Comment: @serhio That wasn't there at the time, but there is an element of personal style here (either *would work*) - the coding standards at my place of work state that the `operator==` should always call `Equals` - no technical reason, but it makes it easier to find if all your code is consistent

Comment: The "return // ???" isn't *unreachable* in terms of the *spec* - but you are right in that it won't ever get there (barring crazy interception).

Comment: @Marc You'd have to be doing something *really* crazy (or just not be thread safe)

Comment: @Rowland Shaw: last one d) :D

Comment: @rowland - indeed; my main point was to highlight the difference between *formally unreachable*, and simply "never gets there".

Comment: "that you could have two objects with the same Id, but different references" I asked the inverse: ReferenceEquals=true and different Ids

Comment: @serhio That's not possible, as for `ReferenceEquals` to return `true` they **must** be the same reference (and cannot be different). Importantly, the reference would be for a single object that (under normal circumstances - you could do some crazy stuff in the property accessor) could only ever have the same value for its property

Comment: @Rowland Shaw: Potentially and theoretically Yes, but practically No, as Fredrik Mörk remarked.

Answer (score 4):

yes,

```
null == null
```

I would refactor your code like this

```
if(x!=null && y!=null)
   return x.id == y.id;
return x == null && y == null;
```

Comment: @serhio: It is a matter of taste, but generally I would prefer implementing the logic in Equals and call it from operator == . Is that really a reason for downvoting?

Answer (score 3):

`ReferenceEquals` already handles the case when both arguments are null — [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals.aspx) states "true if objA is the same instance as objB or if both are null; otherwise, false." regarting its return value.