# Why do NULL fields get called equal?

Tags: advantage-database-server

I'm writing triggers to detect changes in fields in a database, and it appears I have to do really obnoxious things like

```
(SELECT SalesPrice FROM __old) <> (SELECT SalesPrice FROM __new)
or ((SELECT SalesPrice FROM __old) IS NULL and (SELECT SalesPrice FROM __new) IS NOT NULL)
or ((SELECT SalesPrice FROM __old) IS NOT NULL and (SELECT SalesPrice FROM __new) IS NULL)
```

rather than just

```
(SELECT SalesPrice FROM __old) <> (SELECT SalesPrice FROM __new)
```

to accurately detect if a field changed.

Am I missing something, or does Advantage effectively claim that NULL == any value?  Is there a good reason for this behavior?  Is this some weird thing in the SQL definition?  Is there a more succinct way this that doesn't do 3 checks in place of one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is unfortunately how SQL works with NULL values.  NULL is not equal to anything, it is UNKNOWN.  For example, 
somevalue == NULL -> unknown 
somevalue <> NULL -> unknown

As a result it will never pass a "true" check
[Null Values - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29#Three-valued_logic_.283VL.29)

There are a couple of options:
A) Do not allow null values (I recommend combining this with a default value)
B) Use IFNULL to set the field to some value such as

```
(SELECT IFNULL(SalesPrice, -9999) FROM __OLD) <> (SELECT IFNULL(SalesPrice, -9999) FROM __NEW)
```

But I don't know if I necessarily like this since a value must be picked that would not be valid.

Comment: It's not unfortunate; it makes perfect sense. If two columns have no value, how can those non-existent values compare equal? You'll find the same thing with IEEE NaN values.

Comment: @Tomalak My problem is that when a column NULL, SQL effectively says that it is EQUAL to EVERYTHING.  I know that SQL isn't exactly a programming language, but it many language they assume NULL == NULL and nothing else so that you can get a sensible result from comparisons where a NULL may pop up.

Comment: @Edgar - Yeah, not allowing nulls could work in some cases, but there is a difference between 0 and not decided (for example).  However, if IFNULL will work great, as I can easily find suitable invalid values to use in the comparison.  Thanks.

Comment: @EricG: No no no. Most languages assume that `NULL != NULL` and this is a cornerstone of programming. You have to stop thinking of `NULL` as a value; in fact, it is the _lack of one_.

Comment: For many applications, a lack of a value is an extremely important, measurable value.  Now, maybe I'm wrong, but in C, C++, C#, java, php null == null returns true.

C#: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077418/does-null-null

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, NULL does not compare to anything, except the IS [NOT] NULL expression. If I understand you question correctly, the problem here is that NULL must equal to NULL. If that is the case, the check may be simplified to:

```
( SELECT CASE WHEN n.SalesPrice IS NULL and o.SalePrice IS NULL THEN TRUE
         ELSE n.SalesPrice = o.SalesPrice END
  FROM __old o, __new n )
```